# How to print the instance variables of a ruby object

Tags: ruby, class, object, instance-variables

```
class Packet
  def initialize(name, age, number, array)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @number = number
    @neighbors = array
  end 
end

p1 = Packet.new("n1", 5, 2, [1,2,3,4])

puts p1.name
```

I have the above code, but whenever I execute the puts statement I get the error that name is not a method.

I don't know any other way to print the name of p1.

How to print name?

Comment: If don't want to provide assessors, `puts p1.instance_variable_get(:@name)` will print `"n1"`.

Comment: You have already gotten answers with the solution, but here's how you could have arrived at the solution yourself: read the error message! What does it say? It says that you don't have a method called `name`. So what do you do? You create a method called `name`! What do you want that method to do? You want it to return the value of the instance variable `@name`. So … `def name; @name end`. You could have arrived at that solution just by following what the error message already tells (well, suggests) you to do.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand that. I actually did do that but I remember there being some shortcut in Ruby that is commonly used but I forgot it since I haven't used Ruby in a long time. Hence, why I asked the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is that while you have instance variables, you haven't made them accessible. `attr_reader :variable_name` will let you read them, `attr_writer :variable_name` will let you write them, and `attr_accessor :variable_name` will let you do both. These are metaprogramming shortcuts built into Ruby's standard library so you don't have to write methods to read or write variables by yourself. They take a symbol, which is the instance variable name.

```
class Packet
  attr_reader :name, :age, :number, :array
  def initialize(name, age, number, array)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @number = number
    @neighbors = array
  end 
end

p1 = Packet.new("n1", 5, 2, [1,2,3,4])

puts p1.name
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, instance variables and methods are completely separate. Using dot-syntax on an object will *only call a method*. Fortunately, there are a few utility methods to help define attributes on classes (essentially turning an instance variable into a method):

- `attr_reader :var` - creates a method named `var`, which will return the value of `@var`
- `attr_writer :var` - creates a method named `var=`, which will set the value of `@var`
- `attr_accessor :var` - creates *both* of the above methods

If you want `name` to be accessible through a method, simply use `attr_reader :name`:

```
class Packet
  attr_reader :name

  # ...
end
```

and then:

```
Packet.new("n1", 5, 2, [1,2,3,4]).name # => "n1"
```